# How to remove Recent Item bookmark from Gnome shell standard "save windows"

Tags: 12.04, gnome, nautilus

I search all around the internet till the 6th page of result on google with very precise search, but I can't figure how I can do that.

I'm working with last updated ubuntu 12.04 and gnome shell, and I wonder how I can REMOVE and I say remove not clear or avoid feeding but remove completly the "recent item" bookmark you can see in the standard save windows of gnome shell
here's a picture (in french it's "Récemment utilisés"):

Sorry not enought point to post image to see what I talk about, just do that:
-open gedit
-type anything
-save your file
-Now that windows got a "recent item" and I want it DOWN

I cannot reward point, but I would if I could for the guy finding a solution, and a bonus point if you find a way to remove it every where it appears in gnome shell.

Thank you for time.

Antoine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look around, but I can't obviously find a solution. Since you are running 12.04, this is presumably a GTK3 file chooser dialog.

The GTK3 global settings (`/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` or `$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`) should understand keys `gtk-recent-files-limit` and `gtk-recent-files-max-age`, which will allow you to empty the list (but this will only empty the list, not remove it as you ask for).

Gedit has a gsettings key `org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents` but I think this only controls the number of recent files in the `File` menu. The gsettings [schema](https://gist.github.com/f90a230bf6077cbaa967) for the GTK file dialog does not appear to contain any useful option.

The same issue is discussed [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=131878), which suggests recompiling GTK (note this is for GTK2 and might be a bit different for GTK3) with the behaviour disabled - I can't find any simpler solution for the moment.

Comment: All right I'll try it maybe, if I find enought motivation.
thank you for the precision At least now I know where the problem precisely